# store data from a form using just HTML

Tags: html, excel

I want to create a form (will be filled by users) and store the data in excel stylesheet  without using php just HTML ,is that possible?

I dont want to store data an a database.

I have tried to use google doc but it's not that good because the validation messages are generated depending on the browser language.

Comment: Use [HTML5 cache to store things](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: Hahah, Can you bring me back to zero on my suggestion?

Comment: @KLD I didn't down-vote your answer for me I am thankfull for every answer

Comment: @KLD or I think it's accidently sorry I think it's ok now!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, HTML pages cannot write files. You need a server to do this.

The best you can do is generate CSV data in a textarea that the user could then copy and paste to a local file, then load that into Excel.

Comment: thank you thats what I want to know, that I should have a server to do that

Comment: There are services that do this for you, such as SurveyMonkey and Google Forms.

Comment: I have tried google form but the problem is like I have said the validation message depend on the language of the browser

Comment: Julie you'll be able to get all the input written to a text file and then modify it in excel with what I've provided below. The PHP script is simple and you won't need to set anything up on your webhost or require anything special from your users.

Answer (score 22):

The unqualified response of "You can't write a file from HTML" is ***inaccurate***. While you may need to add some "hidden" fields in your HTML (in order to simplify the exporting of only the data requested and not the questions or other text) it is ***ABSOLUTELY*** possible to do this. I've done JUST THAT in the code below - and all I use is JavaScript.  No Server required, No Database required, No PHP required.

Below is the code and a link to the JSFiddle page where you can see it in action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillHidTable(){
    var htqf; //-- hidden field
    var rf; //-- retrieved field
    for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) {
        rf = "htqf"+i;
        document.getElementById(rf).innerHTML = document.getElementById("Q"+i+"CALC").value;
    }
    tableToExcel('hidTable', 'Analysis Results');
}

var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
</script>

<title>HTML Form Data to Excel</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .divCenMid{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrCenMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrCenTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}
    .allbdrLtMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrLtTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="QMSTable">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "4"> QMS Assessment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> No</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Criteria</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtMid"> Question</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q1</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Quality Unit Independency</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q1CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q1CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q2</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Apply PICS GMP</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Which GMP regulation do you use?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q2CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q2CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q3</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Deviation or Non-conformance</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q3CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q3CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q4</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Complaint</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q4CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q4CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="hidTable" style="display: none">
    <table id="testTable">
        <caption>Supplier Risk Analysis</caption>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Q1</td>
            <td>Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
            <td id="htqf1">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q2</td>
            <td>Apply PICS GMP?</td>
            <td id="htqf2">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q3</td>
            <td>Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
            <td id="htqf3">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q4</td>
            <td>Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
            <td id="htqf4">-</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="fillHidTable()" value="Export Data to Excel">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/MitchinThailand/LV9vr/

if you want more details feel free to holler.

Comment: I think this answer need more upVotes.. working fine thanks mitch lizar

Comment: Thank you @kamesh , I appreciate your response... and I'm disappointed that there are people with more experience than myself who have blindly accepted the "approved" answer that you "just can't do this". It took me several weeks of looking at other resources to get code that would actually do what I needed - and it DOES work (though it can be a bit cumbersome at times. P.S. I'm working on building script that will construct the "hidden" fields automatically - but it's taking some time. Best of luck to you!

Comment: @MitchLizar thank you for your hard work , I have tested your code in your case a user fill a form and when he validate, the excel file will be stored on the user machine.What I have asked Is I want to store the data in one file on my PC to do some work on the data later.

Comment: @Julie - I do not understand - my code provides you an Excel spreadsheet from the data filled out on the HTML form. Do you wish to save the data WITH the form (maintain the HTML access to the data) on the users computer?

Comment: what an amazing answer!! exactly what i was searching for. Is there any way that for every new survey, it updates the same excel book with another sheet or a new row for example?

Comment: @Mike - I've just tried the code again and it's not working now. I'm suspect of something about the new excel - give me some more time to look at it again (it's 3AM now) and I'll try to update this later.

Answer (score 1):

As it is not possible to save html form data to a file using javascript because of some security reason so for my solution i just use the TCPDF for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `data:` URL with the [download](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download) attribute:

```
<a download="test.csv" href="data:text/csv,foo,bar,baz">
```

You'll need to use JavaScript to build such URL from form data and insert/update appropriate link in the document.

Answer (score -1):

To do what you want to do simply it will not be possible without php or some advanced HTML5 local storage.

I've done this by using simple PHP script to have form data get saved to a .txt file and then open the resulting .txt file in Excel and use the text to columns feature.

I have a HTML form which collects a field where people enter their email address. I want the form to post the email address to a text file. Please help! Will award maximum points to the one who will answer me correctly!
2 years ago Report Abuse
Additional Details
Please paste entire code to do this!
2 years ago

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="nameofyourscripthere.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

Create a new page saved as .php with this code. All you need is the form and the PHP script on the server for this to work :)

```
<?php
// Get the name they entered in the form
// We'll be naming the file this
$file = $_POST['name'];
// Get the email from the form
$email = $_POST['email'];
// We want the file to be a text file right?
$ex = ".txt";
// Try to open a file named $file$ex (johndoe.txt for example)
// Because this file doesn't exist yet the server creates it
$write = fopen("$file$ex","w");
// Now open the file up again but this time save the email in it
fwrite($write,$email);
// MAKE SURE you close the file!!!
fclose($write);
// The folder that this script is in on the server is where the file we just made was saved
// We can 'rename' it to another folder
// The folder on the server we want to move it to 
$data = "../emails/";
// Now put it all together: This example goes out of the folder we're in and into the folder 'emails'
// The new 'name' would be this now (../emails/johndoe.txt): So now the file is moved to where we want for storage
rename ("$file","$data$file$ex");
// The script is done, send the user to another page (Just read the address below and you'll get it)
// Its just an example fyi change to what you want
header('Location: http://YourWebsiteNameHere.com/contactFo…
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I believe the OP stated "without using php".

Comment: Diodeus, I explain that to do what she wants she will have to use at least a simple php script or html5 storage. Text to columns will give her what she wants in excel. Please don't down vote a thoughtful answer.