# Export HTML table to Excel but Specify Excel Extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, xlsx

I am using this code :

```
var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template=`
      <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <xml>
            <x:ExcelWorkbook>
              <x:ExcelWorksheets> 
                <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  <x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                      <x:DisplayGridlines/>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                </x:ExcelWorksheet>
              </x:ExcelWorksheets>
            </x:ExcelWorkbook>
          </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>
          <table>{table}
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>`,
    base64=function(s){
        return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    },
    format=function(s,c){
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})
    };
return {
    tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
        var table=$(tableId),
            ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
            href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
        return href;
    }
};
```

so, I need to download excel file with.xlsx extension, anyone can help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22526816/6060606

Comment: thank you,but that answer just explains how to export data to excel which i did, I need to specify the excel extention to be .xlsx not .xls 
can you help.

Comment: `window.location.href = <the href you return>` opens the download dialogue window