# Generate Excel File from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, excel, forms

I have a simple HTML form that takes Name, id, checkbox, and radio button. After a user fills out the form - how to generate Excel file from the filled-out form?

I have added the Download button but cannot think of the function required to generate excel file from the form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [store data from a form using just HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360769/store-data-from-a-form-using-just-html)

Comment: Well , my bet is, you need to look for a library that could do this , for my current project I need to convert the page, to a pdf, and there is a library that doesn’t this… so try to look for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a csv file (you can create that easily) and excel can open it.